# $(window).on('focus', ..) function not working on android chrome browser (working fine on firefox android)

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome

I have to trigger page reload event when a tab comes in focus on desktop and mobile browsers. I am using $(window).on('focus', ..) which is working fine on firefox and chrome on desktop and firefox on android but not on chrome. Please suggest solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

Try to focus on `document` and not on `window`.

edit 1 - added answer
try to add an event listner native way:

```
window.addEventListener("focus", function() { 
   alert(1); 
});
```

Comment: try it so : window.addEventListener("focus", function() { alert(1) });